# Allow dragging only when mouse is over a particular element using jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to make a `<div>` draggable only when mouse is over first element inside this `<div>`. When mouse isn't over that first element, whole `<div>` can't be draggable. This is my code:

```
<div id="containers">
  <div id="cont1">foo</div>
  <div id="cont2">bar</div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cont1").mouseenter(function() {
      $("#containers").draggable("enable");
    });
    $("#cont1").mouseleave(function() {
      $("#containers").draggable("disable");
    });
  });
</script>
```

When mouse enter or leave `#cont1`, there is an error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function(index):27 (anonymous function)jquery-1.11.0.js:4995 jQuery.event.special.(anonymous function).handlejquery-1.11.0.js:4624 jQuery.event.dispatchjquery-1.11.0.js:4292 elemData.handle
```

Comment: I want achieve something like windows in Windows. When you drag title bar, whole window is dragging, but you can't drag window by dragging content inside.

Comment: Use the `handle` property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`handle`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-handle) option of draggable widget:

```js
$("#containers").draggable({
  handle: "#cont1"
});
```

```css
#containers {
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
}
#cont1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
#cont2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="containers">
  <div id="cont1">foo</div>
  <div id="cont2">bar</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="containers" style="height: 200px;width: 200px;background-color: blanchedalmond">
    <div id="cont1">foo</div>
    <div id="cont2">bar</div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#cont1").mouseenter(function() {
       $("#containers").draggable({ disabled: false });
   });
   $("#cont1").mouseleave(function() {
      $("#containers").draggable({ disabled: true });
   });
});
</script>
```

Use this code.